# How to map IDs in different formats from source to destination using SSIS

Tags: ssis, data-migration

My source data is in PostgreSQL and my target data is in Common Data Service (D365).

On the source, I have employees with these IDs: 1, 2, 3, 4, ...

On target, the IDs are a little bit more complex (GUID).

How can I map these IDs? I need to know that the employee with the Id **1** (source) corresponds to the worker with the Id **b15a1bd9-50e2-ea11-a81b-000d3a33f94a** (target).

PS: I can't edit the source database.

I appreciate your help.

Best regards,
Ana Alves.

Comment: I guess you are using Kingswaysoft? Have you managed to import any data yet? You need to store both id's. You need to add a custom field in D365 to store the `1` and load it in, then you can lookup on that field and extract the GUID.

Comment: Hi @Nick.McDermaid. Thanks for your answer. That's exactly what I did and it's working. Best regards.